# How do I update YUM repositories to get Postgres9.x version?

Tags: linux, redhat, postgresql, yum

I need to install some Postgres9.1 libs, but "yum list" only shows 8.4 version.

How to "update" yum repo list to get 9.1 version?

My Linux version:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)
```

Comment: See if any 3rd-party repository has it (it's likely because rhel5.9 is a bit old for pgsql91): http://pkgs.org/search/postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the yum repository provided by the PostgreSQL project:

```
rpm -hiv http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/pgdg-redhat91-9.1-5.noarch.rpm
```

or

```
rpm -hiv http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-5-i386/pgdg-redhat91-9.1-5.noarch.rpm
```

That will add their repository for you. See [this document](http://people.planetpostgresql.org/devrim/index.php?/archives/70-How-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.2-on-RHELCentOSScientific-Linux-5-and-6.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

PGDG publishes RHEL 5 packages; see http://yum.postgresql.org/ for instructions.

The package name for PostgreSQL in the PGDG repository is different. That prevents `postgresql` packages from being upgraded with a simple `yum update`. That is by design, because it'd leave you with a surprise major version upgrade - causing at minimum some significant downtime, and probably compatibility problems too.

Read [the release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html) for each major PostgreSQL release between your 8.4 and the current 9.3, i.e read the notes for 9.0, 9.1, 9.2 and 9.3 (especially the compatibility sections).

Then to install 9.3:

```
yum install postgresql93-server postgresql93-contrib
```

This will not *upgrade* your current server. It will add a new one. You can then migrate the data with `pg_upgrade` or a dump and reload, change the port so that 9.3 runs on port 5432, and when you're done, stop and uninstall 8.4.

For more info, see the `README.rpm-dist` at `/usr/share/doc/postgresql93/README.rpm-dist` after installing `postgresql93` packages.